# Como receber um Json em um Campo CLob Java + Spring boot

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

Bom dia tenho uma etidade que um dos campos é um Clob que armazema um Json

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "SEQUENCE_PROPOSAL_UID", length = 3)
private Long sequenceProposalUid;

@NotNull
@JsonProperty
@Column(name = "DETAIL_PROSPECT_PROPOSAL_TEXT")
private Clob detailProspectProposalText;

@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_UID", length = 38)
private Long customerUid;
```

Só que quando faço um get nessa entidade recebo o erro abaixo

```
> Unhandled exception from controller :: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleClobReader]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleClobReader and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a anotação @Lob

```
@Lob
private String detailProspectProposalText;
```